# evaluate exponential using Euler identity

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

let us consider following exponential

$e^{-j*\pi*k/2}$  and  $e^{j*\pi*k/2}$

we can   decompose it as  $cos(\pi*k/2)-j*sin(\pi*k/2)$ and second one  same with plus  sign

$cos(\pi*k/2)+j*sin(\pi*k/2)$

now for $k$ integer,first one is equal to $-j$ and second $j$ right?thanks in advance

Comment: Consider separately, $k$ odd or even and you will see that this is not correct.

Comment: No, the values of $\cos(k\pi/2)$ and $\sin(k\pi/2)$ depend on the value of $k$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for first one  the pattern is $-i,-1,i,1,...$ and for second one the pattern is $i,-1,-i,1,..$

Comment: for $k$ odd values,it should  yes as i said

Comment: when $k=2*m$ when we put we will get  $e^{-j*\pi*m}$ and $e^{j*\pi*m}$

Comment: now it is equal (-1) and 1 right

Comment: Yes, if k is even, that is true.

Comment: if $k$ is odd ?

Comment: Then for first $-i,i$ and for second $i,-i$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. The values of (using your "$j$") notation $e^{j\pi k/2}$ cycle among $1$, $j$, $-1$, and $-j$ in order as $k$ moves through the integers $0,1,2,\ldots$. They cycle in reverse order as you move backwards through the negative integers, which gives you the values for the other expression you wrote.

Said differently, you can write $$e^{\pm j\pi(4n)/2}=1$$
$$e^{\pm j\pi(4n+1)/2}=\pm j$$
$$e^{\pm j\pi(4n+2)/2}=-1$$
$$e^{\pm j\pi(4n+3)/2}=\mp j$$
for integral $n$.

Comment: i mean if $k$ is even and if $k$ is odd

Comment: $k$ even corresponds to the first and third cases (so you get $\pm 1$), and $k$ odd corresponds to the second and fourth cases (so you get $\pm j$).

Comment: In other words, you get $1$ for $k=\ldots,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,\ldots$; you get $-1$ for $k=\ldots,-10,-6,-2,2,6,10,\ldots$; you get $j$ for $k=\ldots,-11,-7,-3,1,5,9,\ldots$; and you get $-j$ for $k=\ldots,-9,-5,-1,3,7,11,\ldots$